# C++: Reading a line as : 'string string;int'

Tags: c++, ifstream, sstream

I have started coding lately(school curriculuim) and ran into a little problem. I want to read a .txt file, the lines are like "firstname lastname;phonenumber".

```
ifstream file("names.txt");

    string line, fname, lname;
    int num;

    while (getline(file, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> fname >> lname >> num;
    }
```

So the problem is that the lastname is  lastname +  ";" + phone number and I don't know how to separate them. Any help is appreciated :)

Edit: Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: Pro-tip: Don't use integers for phone-numbers! Phone-numbers can contain leading zeroes, something that an `int` can't handle. A phone-number can also contain leading explicit `+`, which are also lost in the conversion.

Comment: Also just semantically/logically they are not really numbers, but strings of digits/characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. One relatively simple way is to read `fname` like you do now, then use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with `';'` as the separator (instead of the default newline) to get `lname`. Then you could read into `num`.
2. Get `fname` like you do now. Then get `lname;num` into a second string. [Find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) the semi-colon and create two [sub-strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), one for `lname` and one for `num`. Then [convert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) the string containing `num` into an integer (with the caveat mentioned in my comment to the OP).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `;` as a separator to `getline` when extracting `lname`.

```
std::ifstream file("names.txt");

for (std::string line; getline(file, line);) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string fname, lname;
    int num;
    iss >> fname;
    getline(iss, lname, ';');
    iss >> num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [string.find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to find the semicolon, and then use [string.substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to split the string.